# Android widget button unclickable when adding more than one widget

Tags: android, android-widget

I have a widget which is basically a big button (with some images in the background). The button works fine if there's just one widget on the home screen (or more than one after a phone reboot), but if I try to add another widget, the button suddenly stops reacting (on the second widget).

Been struggling with this for months now. Hopefully you'll be able to assist.

```java
public class StatsWidget extends AppWidgetProvider {
    public static String ACTIONWIDGETCLICK = "MyWidgetClick";
    @Override
    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
        Intent intentt = new Intent(context, StatsService.class);
        context.startService(intentt);
        final int N = appWidgetIds.length;
        for (int i=0; i<N; i++) {
            int appWidgetId = appWidgetIds[i];
            RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.main);
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, StatsWidgetActivity.class);
            intent.setAction(ACTIONWIDGETCLICK);
            intent.putExtra("widgetId", appWidgetId);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, appWidgetId, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
            views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.widget_button, pendingIntent);
            appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The only error I see in your code is you forgot to add

```
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```

This must be used when starting an Activity from a service/broadcastreciever/etc. Otherwise are you updating the widget from anywhere else in your app? I recently had a problem with the pending intent unresistering itself because I updated the widget from within my app and didn't add the

```
views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.widget_button, pendingIntent);
```

to the update code.

Hope this helps